# Get display records in another time zone (SQL Server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do make a statement a DateTime field is between the start and end of the current day in (UTC + 4).

My SQL Server table contains records in time zone UTC+10 (field SENT_TIME).

I want to display all entries for current day from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 in time zone UTC+4; server time zone is UTC+10.

Below is my SQL query, but it seems to work incorrectly:

```
SELECT SENT_TIME,GETDATE()
FROM Table
WHERE (CAST(SENT_TIME AS DATE) = (CAST(DATEADD(hour,- 7, (GETDATE())) AS DATE))
```

How to fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What flavour of database are you using

Comment: Note that converting time-zones like this might work incorrectly, due to things like DST, data from different sources etc. 
It's recommended to do one of the following (1) always store the data as UTC (convert in INSERT time) or (2) use datetimeoffset data type, to store the data with the time zone.

Comment: A few things: please provide table structure and sample data, and also make sure you clarify 'it works incorrectly'. Does that mean no results come back, the wrong results come back, etc.

Comment: I would like to emphasise point 2 of @ShaharGvirtz comment: time differences between time zones are not constant for a variety of reasons, including DTS (Daylight Time Saving) changes happen at different dates in different countries. Additionally DTS in northern and southern hemisphere shift time in opposite directions therefore time difference (between any 2 regions) is not guaranteed to be constant. If working with dates from different time zones it is safest to use `datetimeoffset`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not concerned about DTS and working purely with UTC then your query should look like this:

```
-- Time Offset calculation steps (shown for clarity)
SELECT GETDATE() AS LocalNow, GETUTCDATE() AS UTCNow,
    DATEADD( HOUR, 4, GETUTCDATE()) AS UTC4Now, DATEADD( HOUR, 10, GETUTCDATE()) AS UTC10Now,
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD( HOUR, 4, GETUTCDATE())), 0) AS UTC4DayStart,
    DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD( HOUR, 4, GETUTCDATE())), 1) AS UTC4NextDayStart,
    DATEADD( HOUR, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD( HOUR, 4, GETUTCDATE())), 0)) AS UTC4DayStartInUTC10,
    DATEADD( HOUR, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD( HOUR, 4, GETUTCDATE())), 1)) AS UTC4NextDayStartInUTC10

-- Your query should become this
SELECT SENT_TIME, DATEADD( HOUR, -6, SENT_TIME ) AS SENT_TIME_UTC4
FROM Table
WHERE DATEADD( HOUR, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD( HOUR, 4, GETUTCDATE())), 0)) <= SENT_TIME
    AND SENT_TIME < DATEADD( HOUR, 6, DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD( HOUR, 4, GETUTCDATE())), 1))
```

Note: `GETDATE()` returns DTS adjusted time.